# If $f^{\ast}:\ \mathcal{O}_Y(Y)\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is injective, then $fX\subset Y$ is dense.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm stuck on the following exercise, which seems rather simple:

Let $f: (X,\mathcal{O}_X)\longrightarrow(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ be a morphism of varieties and assume that the corresponding morphism of $k$-algebras $f^{\ast}:\ \mathcal{O}_Y(Y)\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is injective. Show that $fX$ is dense in $Y$.

A hint would be very welcome.

Comment: Consider making the title more descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

Else,   if $y \in Y \setminus \overline{f(X)},$ try to  find $\phi \in \mathcal O_Y(Y)$  zero on $\overline{f(X)}$ and  such that $\phi(y)=1$. Then...